# How's Mule <object-to-string-transformer> different than message.getPatyloadAsString()

Tags: mule

I've a soap service flow which gets inbound request through `<cxf:proxy-service>`. I have a set payload right after it to get payload as String.

Here is my flow:

```
<flow name="soapService">
    <http:inbound-endpoint address="${service.address}" exchange-pattern="request-response">
        <cxf:proxy-service wsdlLocation="classpath:service.wsdl" namespace="http://pennmutual.com/services/mvi" service="MVIService" enableMuleSoapHeaders="false"/>                
    </http:inbound-endpoint>        
    <set-payload value="#[message.payloadAs(java.lang.String)]"/>
  .
  .
  .
 </flow>
```

`<set-payload value="#[message.payloadAs(java.lang.String)]"/>` works but if I replace it with `<object-to-string-transformer>`, it doesn't work.

How are these 2 inherently different?

**UPDATE:**
On replacing `<set-payload value="#[message.payloadAs(java.lang.String)]"/>` with `<object-to-string-transformer>` in my above flow, `#[payload]` gives `com.ctc.wstx.sr.ValidatingStreamReader@429eb61a` instead of the atcual `XML`

Comment: Both should be equivalent. So what do you mean by "it doesn't work".

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`message.payloadAs(java.lang.String)` relies on Mule's auto-transformation framework: I supposed it picks `<xml:dom-to-xml-transformer>` instead of `<object-to-string-transformer>` as the most appropriate transformer.

Comment: pefecto!! You're awesome :)